# ES6 Template String testbed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, template-strings

I'm really interested in finding out about [ES6 Template Strings](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/template-strings/) and have been doing a little bit of reading on the feature.

However now that Chrome Canary does not support it (although maybe I'm wrong about that!) is there anywhere/anything I can use to try out this new functionality? Any browser beta around that does?

I've already enabled Experimental Javascript Features inside `chrome://flags`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only [supported in Traceur at the moment](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Template_Strings).

You can play with it in [their REPL](http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html).

[es6fiddle.net](http://es6fiddle.net) doesn't seem to support it yet, but probably will soon.

Mozilla is [working on it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688857) so expect to see it in nightly builds soon as well.

Comment: Template strings are officially supported in Firefox since the release of version 34! https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 1):

It's Supported in

1. Edge
2. Firefox
3. Chrome/Opera
4. Webkit

Missing in safari ;( though

cough *safari is the new ie* cough

[source](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding template strings and support for ES6 features**

I would also use traceur to play around with most ES6 features, but have a look at [this ES6 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), it's invaluable when you want to find out which platforms/transpilers support which features.

For anyone else landing on this question, go and check out tagtree's videos onn ES6 features.

To see template **strings**, **arrow syntax** and **desctructuring**, have a look at this [**free tagtree tutorial screencast**](http://tagtree.tv/ecmascript-6-episode-1?share_code=territorial-cableway), no registration is required.